# Using sed to remove the beginning of a line until capitalized word

Tags: regex, sed, regex-greedy

I am trying to use sed to remove the beginning of a number of lines. The goal is to remove in each line all characters until a word with two consecutive capital letters.

The input will be always something similar to:

```
1 where did you get ACQUIRE, obtain, come by, receive, gain, earn, win, come into, take 
2 I got your letter: RECEIVE, be sent, be in receipt of, be given.
3 your tea is getting cold: BECOME, grow, turn, go.
4 get the children from school: FETCH, collect, go for, call for, pick up, bring, deliver, convey, ferry, transport.
5 the chairman gets £650,000 a year: EARN, be paid, take home, bring in, make, receive, collect, gross; informal pocket, bank, rake in, net, bag.
6 have the police got their man?: APPREHEND, catch.
```

And I want the output to be:

```
ACQUIRE, obtain, come by, receive, gain, earn, win, come into, take 
RECEIVE, be sent, be in receipt of, be given.
BECOME, grow, turn, go.
FETCH, collect, go for, call for, pick up, bring, deliver, convey, ferry, transport.
EARN, be paid, take home, bring in, make, receive, collect, gross; informal pocket, bank, rake in, net, bag.
APPREHEND, catch.
```

I got to build this:

```
sed -n 's/^.*[A-Z]\{2\}//p'
```

but this expression also removes the capitalized word. Any clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is the lack of look-ahead and non-greedy options. One way to solve this is to do two substitutions. The first one takes the text you want, save it as group 1 and append it after a newline character, then remove all data until that newline character, like this:

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]\{2,\}.*\)/\n\1/; s/[^\n]*\n//' infile
```

It yields:

```
ACQUIRE, obtain, come by, receive, gain, earn, win, come into, take 
RECEIVE, be sent, be in receipt of, be given.
BECOME, grow, turn, go.
FETCH, collect, go for, call for, pick up, bring, deliver, convey, ferry, transport.
EARN, be paid, take home, bring in, make, receive, collect, gross; informal pocket, bank, rake in, net, bag.
APPREHEND, catch.
```

Answer (score 1):

This should have worked in `awk`, but it gives wrong output on line `5`

```
awk '{print substr($0,match($0,/[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]/))}' file
ACQUIRE, obtain, come by, receive, gain, earn, win, come into, take
RECEIVE, be sent, be in receipt of, be given.
BECOME, grow, turn, go.
FETCH, collect, go for, call for, pick up, bring, deliver, convey, ferry, transport.
5 the chairman gets
APPREHEND, catch.
```

`match` finds the two first uppercase letter, then `substr` uses this to print the last part of the line.